# Rsyslog doesn't log TCP after upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, rsyslog

I was using Ubuntu 10.04 until last week for storing the log informations of a external device with rsyslog.

After upgrading to Ubuntu 12.4 the logging of TCP doesn't works any more. There are just no packets visible - not even with tcpdump - old Ubuntu machine still sees the packets.

UDP works with the identical configuration on the Ubuntu machine and a "use UDP" on the external device.

**Are there any changes in rsyslog that could explain this?**

My `rsyslog.conf` file looks like this (with more comments):

```
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

$KLogPath /proc/kmsg

# provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514

# provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514

###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################

$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog

if $fromhost-ip startswith '192.168.0.10' then /var/log/caliDevice.log
& ~
# local/regular rules, like
'.' /var/log/syslog.log

$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem with some workarounds [here on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/789174):

Options are:

1. Run `rsyslog` as root by removing the `$PrivDropToUser` and `$PrivDropToGroup` options, or possibly overriding them in `/etc/resolv.conf.d/` files (I'm not sure if this is possible or not).
2. Use the 'Sleep' workaround suggested on the thread (git commit).
3. Listen on a port > 1024
4. Pay upstream for 2 weeks work to get the fix done correctly.

Comment: If you have two accounts with the same name you can ask a moderator [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201) to combine them for you.